# Epson SX115 All-in-One printer scanner not recognized

Tags: scanner

I am very new to Ubuntu. I have an Epson SX115 All-in-One Printer. I use the Ubuntu 12.04 OS. I can print in it but how do I make the scanner on the printer work?

Answer (score 0):

in the terminal paste

```
dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-epsom-inkjet-printer-Epson Stylus T13
```

in the        printer setting page
the printer device URI

```
usb://EPSON/T13%20T22E?serial=MEJZ004690%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20
```

if connected to usb and local printer(T13 is my modedl no)
 this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the idea.

I have a Epson SX115 All-in-One printer scanner and it was trying to use some driver for 2000 series. It was sending the job without any errors.

The T13 driver works. There is a deb file there which make install nice and easy. And you can download it here:

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=16878&DSCCHK=4be73117a4e330f8f4b08216d6d243176481fae6